# How to fetch collection of CMAEntry by their ids from Contentful using Contentful CMA

Tags: java, api

I use Contentful CMA. I have `List<String> entriesIds`. I want to fetch entries by their ids from Contentful space so that I can edit them and publish my changes to Contentful. The code below works perfectly fine, but I want to fetch entries making just 1 request.

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class ProductIsAvailableDto {
    private String productId;
    private Boolean isAvailable;
}

private final CMAClient contentfulClientForUpdate;

for (ProductIsAvailableDto product : productIsAvailableDtoList) {
    CMAEntry cmaEntry = contentfulClientForUpdate.entries().fetchOne(product.getProductId());
    cmaEntry.setField(ContentfulFieldsConstants.IS_AVAILABLE, DEFAULT_LOCALE, product.getIsAvailable());
    cmaEntry = contentfulClientForUpdate.entries().update(cmaEntry);
            contentfulClientForUpdate.entries().publish(cmaEntry);
}
```

I faced a method as below.

```
com.contentful.java.cma.ModuleEntries#fetchAll(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>)
```

But I really can't understand how to specify the query param. I tried to make smth as below.

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("ids", new Gson().toJson(productIsAvailableDtoList.stream()
                .map(ProductIsAvailableDto::getProductId)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ));
        CMAArray<CMAEntry> cmaArray = contentfulClientForUpdate.entries().fetchAll(hashMap);
```

But it does not work. In official docs I found only the opportunity to fetch a single entry by id, but I need to fetch a list of entries by ids. It would be great if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(
  "sys.id[in]", 
  productIsAvailableDtoList.stream()
    .map(ProductIsAvailableDto::getProductId)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")
));
CMAArray<CMAEntry> cmaArray = contentfulClientForUpdate.entries().fetchAll(hashMap);
```

It works) Thanks for attention.